# Is there an compliance test for SMTP servers? (e.g. equivalent to ACID browser test)

Tags: testing, smtp

I am looking at developing an implementation of an SMTP server for a project that I want to work on. (Note: I haven't ruled out using an existing implementation just exploring my options.)

I am curious to know if there is an automated test suite available somewhere that tests compliance with the SMTP standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of one (there very well may be one).

Even though I just wrote an SMTP server, it was for a very specific use case talking to another specific server. If you actually intend to work on the wild internet, I would strongly suggest that you use an off the self solution.

On the one hand, we have the long standing SMTP standards. On the other, we have the actual implementations out in the wild. These are not necessarily the same thing. Ideally things have quieted down over the years, but the simple truth is that there is a lot of just flat out "lore" encoded in to the modern servers, lore acquired through just fighting the problems of interoperability with other "in the wild" servers.

Most likely, if you craft your own, it will "mostly" work, and if that's fine for you, then move ahead. But if it's for something more important, I would suggest just going with one of the major email implementations.

Comment: Thanks, and I would love to use an implementation that is already written, but a classic mail server won't work for my purposes. One of the existing server implementations that gives me the messages as an object to work with would work, but I have to investigate the solutions in node.js to see if they actually do that or not.

Comment: What exactly are you doing? If you're willing to write an SMTP server, then write a simple one and stick Postfix in front of it -- then let it route to your system. Then you only have to support one SMTP server, instead of all of them, and only a subset of SMTP at that. Postfix handles the hard work. If your server is down, Postfix queues stuff up for you until it comes back. You just let it start and leave it alone. Really robust and really powerful. If not that, Postfix has other options (like proemial and the like).